# phonegap cordova menu grid

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, grid-layout

I'm developing a mobile app using phonegap/cordova. I want my main menu to be a set of icons with a short text below, all aligned in a grid layout (2 lines x 3 columns for example). 
I'm also using jquerymobile. For my "page" I have a fixed "header" and "footer" regions and the "content" is currently:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive" >
   <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
      <a href="#"><p><img src="./img/menu1.png"></p><h2>OPT1</h2></a>
   </div></div>
   <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
      <a href="#"><p><img src="./img/menu2.png"></p><h2>OPT2</h2></a>
    </div></div>                    
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
      <a href="#"><p><img src="./img/menu3.png"></p><h2>OPT3</h2></a>
    </div></div>                    
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
      <a href="#"><p><img src="./img/menu4.png"></p><h2>OPT4</h2></a>
    </div></div>                    
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
      <a href="#"><p><img src="./img/menu5.png"></p><h2>OPT5</h2></a>
    </div></div>                    
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
      <a href="#"><p><img src="./img/menu6.png"></p><h2>OPT6</h2></a>
    </div></div>                    
</div>
```

I want the grid's height to be equal to the "content"s height either by adjusting the grid overall height or by adjust the rows height. I don't want to define a fixed height because the menu should adjust to different screen sizes. (well maybe the height could be a number if some JS could change it accordingly)

There are some approaches to this on the web but I could not find any that automatically adjusts height. 
Example here: http://www.vjkhan.com/jquery-mobile-jqm-grid-with-images-and-captions/

The solution can by of any type... CSS, JS, etc...

Many thanks for any suggestion!

Cheers!

Comment: could you provide jsfiddel ?

Comment: The question remains unanswered... I wonder if it lacks information. The objective is just to divide the "content" like a grid adjusted to the available width and height. The width part is easy, the question is about the height.